# Shift items to the right then add element to array

Tags: java

I am struggling to figure this out. I am working on a project and it would require me to shift all the elements in the array to the right then add the new element at index 0. I am well aware that ArrayLists would make this easier but I want to stick to normal arrays for this

What is is supposed to look like

original {2, 3, 4, null}

New {1, 2, 3, 4)

This is current code I have.

```
while (scnr.hasNext()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          if (scnr.hasNext()) {
            data[i + 1] = data[i]; 
          }
        }
        data[0] = scnr.next();
        count++;
      }
      scnr.close();
```

My issue is that I can add the first 2 elements, but the elements after the second are all the same. i.e. {2, 3, 3, 3} instead of the the {1, 2, 3, 4}

Note: The reason I am using count is due to the fact that there are many null values that I don't want to add and I don't want that to add into the runtime complexity.

Comment: Is this a recurring operation? If so, maybe you want to consider using a linked list instead? Or if array is a must, use ArrayList, it already implements this for your convenience.

Comment: you should start moving items from the end.

Comment: *Hint:* Use method [`System.arraycopy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) to do the "move" of existing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As karakfa commented, it looks like the way that you are moving across the array is from left to right, which means that the first element you move over is successful, but all the elements after that will be the same.

Think like this:

```
index  : 0 |  1|  2|...
element: 2 |  3|  4|...
```

If you start at index 0, then overwrite index 1, so the new array is:

```
index  : 0 |  1|  2|...
element: 2 |  2|  4|...
```

If you then try to copy the previous value (3) to the next index, when it looks for that 3 it will find a 2 because you already overwrote the 3!

Going the opposite way will work much better. Basically you want to reverse the direction you access the array.